# How to return only if a condition is true?

Tags: scala, playframework

I am still getting the hang of Scala and functional programming.

I am trying to implement an authentication method, but I only want to return if the password matches the hash and I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Please forgive the code below, I am still struggling trying to wrap my head around functional. Hopefully, I have given enough to illustrate what I want to accomplish. I only want to return a result, **IF** and **ONLY IF** the password matches the supplied password, else I want it to act like nothing was found.

```
def authenticate(name: String, password: String): Option[Member] = {
  DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
    SQL("select * from member where lower(membername)={membername}").on(
    'membername -> name.toLowerCase()
  ).as(Member.member.singleOpt)

    if(BCrypt.checkpw(password, Member.member.password)) {
       Member.member.singleOpt
    } else {
       null
    }
  }
}
```

I am using PlayFramework and Anorm. But, I think this is more of a general Scala question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`as(Member.member.singleOpt)` returns an `Option[Member]`. You can `filter` an `Option` just like any collection, which will allow you to filter out a user with bad credentials.

```
def authenticate(name: String, password: String): Option[Member] = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
        SQL("select * from member where lower(membername)={membername}").on(
            'membername -> name.toLowerCase()
        ).as(Member.member.singleOpt)
        .filter(member => BCrypt.checkpw(password, member.password))
    }
}
```

The inner function of `filter` will only be called if the `Member` is found. If `BCrypt.checkpw(password, member.password)` is false, then `Some(member)` will become `None`, so `authenticate` will return `None` when the credentials are incorrect.

Comment: heh. beat me to posting something almost identical. +1  :)

Answer (score 2):

The return type is Option which means it must be either Some (containing a single value) or None (containing nothing).  Member.member.password should be of type Option[Member] already so the else case should probably be None (sub class of any Option).

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option

Answer (score 1):

Your method returns an `Option[Member]` which is good functional style. If your authentication passes you can return `Some[Member]` which is what `Member.member.singleOpt` is. Otherwise return `None` instead of `null`.